# How to check a string has only numbers?

Tags: apex

I need to check if the Lead Postal code has only numbers in my Apex code.

Postal code can have alphanumeric.

Comment: Postal Codes are often alphanumeric outside the US. You should probably make sure which country is addressed before blindly assuming that the postal code must one particular format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are enforcing it somewhere else, US Zip codes can be alpha-numeric if someone enters a 9 digit zip - so I tend to use this pattern to cover both:

```
public static Boolean CheckValidZip(String sZip) {
return Pattern.matches('\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?',sZip);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use a regular expression `^[0-9]+$` with a pattern matcher to check this.

**Update** As pointed out by Mike Chale in the comments you can also use: `^\d+$`

Untested Example:

```
Pattern isnumbers = Pattern.Compile('^[0-9]+$');
Matcher postalMatch = isnumbers.matcher(PostalCode);

if(postalMatch.Matches()){
    //has only numbers
}
```

Comment: The '\d' character class is also available as a shorthand option.

Comment: Thanks.whats the difference between  (^[0-9]+$ )  and ('[0-9]*')

Comment: Long answer: check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.

Comment: Short answer: the ^ represents the beginning of the line, $ is the end. The + represents 1 or more matches and * is any number of matches.

Comment: @MikeChale Thanks for adding the extra info for Vipul

Comment: Regex will work, and are, I think, the only way to go prior to API 26? But now we have isNumeric, as Arun pointed out. I'm hesitant to invoke a regex unless I *absolutely* have to. Regex's aren't always the speediest thing in the world.

Comment: One more comment about Regex's and this situation. The initial question deals with postal codes, which, despite my love for native string methods, may not work here. isNumeric() will accept a decimal point "." as a valid part of a "string of numeric digits". Therefore, "277.3" would pass IsNumeric() which I'm guessing the OP doesn't want. Additionally, the Regex's given here will accept ONLY numbers, which again the OP may not want as, at least US based Postal codes are more and more often in a 5-4 format. Here's a regex for that.
(^\d{5,}\-{0,1}\d{4,}$)

Comment: @KevinP Actually, `^\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?$` would be the correct format in Apex Code.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the update. Sorry I have a tendency to write regexs in my "native" language (ruby) often forget to translate.

Answer (score 16):

Apex comes with range of methods within String class, below i provided the link

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm

We doesn't need to use the Pattern class here. There is instance method in apex String class

isNumeric()

**Example:**

```
String numeric = '123';
system.debug('Is Numeric :: '+numeric.isNumeric()); //returns true


String alphanumeric = '123abc';
system.debug('Is Numeric :: '+alphanumeric.isNumeric()); //returns false
```

Kindly let me know in case of any clarification

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that returns true if the input is a positive or negative number.

```
public Boolean isNumber(String str) {
     Pattern isnumbers = Pattern.Compile('^[-]?[0-9]+$');
     Matcher numberMatch = isnumbers.matcher(str);
     return numberMatch.Matches();
}
```